# Unable to play in WMP when converting to ID3v2.3 with eyeD3

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, id3

I store my MP3s on my NAS. I mount a CIFS share on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and manage my music using Beets. However, I also access my MP3s through my Windows desktop using Windows Media Player.

Beets tags files in ID3v2.4, which WMP (along with Windows 7 File Explorer) can't read. So I thought I would script it up to convert the tags to v2.3 using `eyeD3`.

After running `eyeD3 --to-v2.3 *.mp3`, the files no longer play at all in WMP. However, if I convert them back to v2.4 with eyeD3 they play fine again (although the ID3 info still can't be read).

If I convert the tags using Foobar2000 on Windows, everything works correctly.

What might be causing this incompatibility with eyeD3? I would much rather script the conversion (or write a Beets plugin to do so) rather than having to convert them in Windows with Foobar.

Comment: Any non-standard tags/frames in your files?

Comment: What's the exact error message that WMP displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but beets now [supports ID3v2.3](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/v1.3.2/reference/config.html#id3v23).

Comment: Also, date added queries! Nice update.